# Foreach loop has some issues on Toasting a Message scheduled with time

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, foreach

I have set time using an alarm manager. I have a list of stored time in a `sqlite` database, so that when each of the stored time clocks a Toast has to be fired , but this seems not working.

```
foreach (var list in alarm)
{
    var hour = Int32.Parse(list.Substring(0, 2));
    var minute = Int32.Parse(list.Substring(3, 2));
    SetToast(hour, minute);
}
```

I printed `hour` and `minute`, it shows that the list of them (Time) is available but not working.
Even when i remove `foreach` and i put time directly like `SetToast(12,04);`, it works , But on the stored time in `sqlite` doesn't work,  why is the stored time not looping ?

Comment: are you catching any exceptions?  Are you sure that your data has two valid int string in it?

Comment: yes   @Jason it does ,  and no exceptions am catching

Comment: what if instead of using Toast you just write to the console?

Comment: @jason thats not necessary , the thing is the toast is scheduled by an alarm , so i have a list of time to be tested by the alarm so that it makes a toast when the scheduled time has reached

Comment: I'm suggesting that calling Toast multiple times in a tight loop might have side effects that are masking the real issue that you are having, and that using a console output would be a good way to test